# Powershell command to delete windows service runs successfully but service still shows up

Tags: c#, powershell

I have used below powershell command through C# to delete windows service

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='MyService'").delete()
```

The command runs successfully and returns

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 0
PSComputerName   :
```

When I execute the below query using ServiceController

```
ServiceController.GetServices().Any(s => s.ServiceName == "MyService")
```

it returns True. So the service is still present in services. How is that so? Is there a way to identify or wait till service is removed.

Comment: Are you trying to stop or totally remove the service?

Comment: @Jess I am trying to remove the service.